# taskwarrior - limit calendar month output

Tags: tmux, cygwin, taskwarrior

I am working on writing a tmux script to create a fun tmux environment in cygwin.

When I type 'task calendar' the output appears to look fine, but when I run the same command through my tmux script, the word wrapping creates a poorly formatted output.

This is my super basic tmux script.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

tmux split-window -v ;
tmux split-window -h top ;
tmux select-pane -t 0;
tmux split-window -h mc;
tmux select-pane -t 0;
tmux split-window -h "view -p ~/Documents/*";
tmux select-pane -t 0;
tmux select-pane -t 3
tmux send-keys 'task calendar' Enter
```

I can't make sense of how-to control the output so the calendar doesn't look like this:

https://pasteboard.co/IwFHW9T.png

You will see `$task` calendar, but this was due to the tmux send-keys 'task calendar' Enter command above.

If I run 'task calendar by itself, the output appears properly, and the lines are lined up as I would expect.

Apologies, as this is my first post, and I'm not super familiar with all of the programming terminology. (mostly self-taught)

I think an easy solution would be to limit the calendar month to a single month output, but I can't find this in the man pages. If you have the solution, can you also explain where I'm going wrong so I can learn from this? :) My brain is toast right now...